# How to Concatenate a string in URL on C#?

Tags: string, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, string-concatenation

I need to replace "fullname" with a value in following URL. "fullname" is a predefined string and it gives a dynamic value. I need help, How to do it in C# ??

for example hear full name=XYZ and i wants to contacte varible

```
string FullName="Mansinh";
string html = @"<a  style=""width:100%%25;height:100%%25"" href=""http://kcs.kayako.com/visitor/index.php?/LiveChat/Chat/Request/_sessionID=34mh1inqnaeliioe3og5tious2t93ip9/_proactive=0/_filterDepartmentID=/_randomNumber=43/_fullName=XYZ/_email=usha%40kcspl.co.in/_promptType=chat""  target=""_blank""> <image style=""width:1340px;height:800px"" src=""/Images/1x1-pixel.png"" /> </a>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

string html = @"http://kcs.kayako.com/visitor/index.php?/LiveChat/Chat/Request/_sessionID=34mh1inqnaeliioe3og5tious2t93ip9/_proactive=0/_filterDepartmentID=/_randomNumber=43/_fullName="

+any string you wants+

"/_email=usha%40kcspl.co.in/_promptType=chat""  target=""_blank"">  ";

Answer (score 5):

Use `StringBuilder` or for simple cases the `+` operator.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder()
sb.Append("The start of the string");
sb.Append(theFullNameVariable);
sb.Append("the end of the string");
string fullUrl = sb.ToString();
```

Or

```
string fullUrl = "The start" + theFullNameVariable + "the end";
```

There is a performance penalty to using `+`, especially if you are using it over several statements instead of one. And in my experiments I've found that about after half a dozen concatenations it is faster to use `StringBuilder`. YMMV

Comment: +1 for mentionning that StringBuilder's is better only after a bunch of strings

Answer (score 1):

Use the `+` operator to concatenate strings. Example:

```
string html = "asdf" + variable + "asdf";
```

Remember to use @ on the literal string after the variable also, when you concatenate a variable into a @ delimited string:

```
string html = @"asdf" + variable + @"asdf";
```

With your string:

```
string html = @"<a  style=""width:100%%25;height:100%%25"" href=""http://kcs.kayako.com/visitor/index.php?/LiveChat/Chat/Request/_sessionID=34mh1inqnaeliioe3og5tious2t93ip9/_proactive=0/_filterDepartmentID=/_randomNumber=43/_fullName=" + FullName + @"/_email=usha%40kcspl.co.in/_promptType=chat""  target=""_blank""> <image style=""width:1340px;height:800px"" src=""/Images/1x1-pixel.png"" /> </a>";
```